# Windows Sandbox - Enable GPU Acceleration

Tags: gpu, windows-sandbox

My Windows Sandbox has very low FPS. I searched for it and discovered that RemoteFX enables GPU acceleration on Sandbox, but RemoteFX was removed from Windows in 2021 due to security conserns.

What is the best way to natively enable GPU on Sandbox, without installing any third-part software?

*I really need a solution to Sandbox only. I cannot use any other virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by adding windows sandbox and windows sandbox client to high performance GPU in my Nvidia control panel.

Comment: can tell us how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a TXT file, such as my.txt, and enter

```
<Configuration>
<VGpu>Enable</VGpu>
</Configuration>
```

Then the extension TXT is changed to WSB, for example, my.wsb. After the sandbox is started from my.wsb, the GPU is enabled in the sandbox

Comment: To be precise, it’s `<vGPU>value</vGPU>`. You need to do this because vGPU is disabled in Windows Sandbox by default.